# Laravel Auth::login "expires" after page reloads

Tags: php, laravel

I've implemented a "custom" login setup for our application as we are using the X-Forwarded-User from our proxy (NB - Internal low-security application before we do down that route!)

Unfortunately, it seems that every time we load the page, the user isn't actually logged in. They are logged in as soon as I do Auth::login, but as soon as the page reloads and I do an Auth::user check, they are not logged in.

As you can see here, this is run via middleware so it's run on every request, but I'm a little confused why I am having to do a login every time the page loads and the user isn't "really" getting logged in.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ValidateForwardedUser
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->header('X-Forwarded-User')) {
            $forwardedUser = $request->header('X-Forwarded-User');

            // This is always empty
            print_r("Logged in user before auth = ".Auth::user()."<br>");

            if (!Auth::check() || Auth::user() != $forwardedUser) {
                if (User::where('email', '=', $forwardedUser)->first()) {
                    $user = User::where('email', '=', $forwardedUser)->first();
                    Auth::login($user);
                } else {
                    $user = new User();
                    $user->email = $forwardedUser;
                    $user->save();
                    Auth::login($user);
                }
            } else {
                // We should never hit this, but we throw an exception so it's debugable if we do!
                throw new \Exception('ValidateForwardedUser Exception #1');
            }

            // This is always populated
            print_r("Logged in user before auth = ".Auth::user()."<br>");

            return $next($request);
        } else {
            // We should never hit this, but we throw an exception so it's debugable if we do!
            throw new \Exception('ValidateForwardedUser Exception #2');
        }
    }
}
```

All routes use the "web" middleware which is shown below (Specifically the problem here appears to be with ValidateForwardedUser)

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateForwardedUser::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\BrowserFilter::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Edit: After some debugging, every refresh of the page creates a new session. This doesn't seem right and might be part of the issue?

Comment: Does your API route have the session middleware on it? Stuff in `routes/api.php` typically does not.

Comment: At the moment, I am not using any api middleware (routes/api.php is empty)
If I'm "supposed" to have something in there for all of this to work, that may be my problem!

All routes are in web.php

Comment: If they're in web.php they should be fine. Fire up `php artisan tinker` and do `config('session')`. What's the value of `driver`?

Comment: => [
     "driver" => "redis",
     "lifetime" => "360",
     "expire_on_close" => false,
     "encrypt" => false,
     "files" => "/var/www/app/storage/framework/sessions",
     "connection" => "session",
     "table" => "sessions",
     "store" => null,
     "lottery" => [
       2,
       100,
     ],
     "cookie" => "xx_xx_portal_session",
     "path" => "/",
     "domain" => "CORRECTDOMAINHERE",
     "secure" => null,
     "http_only" => true,
     "same_site" => "lax",
   ]

Comment: Is your redis connection working?

Comment: It is - I tested with file aswell and got the same result. Every page load generated a new session.

Comment: That sounds like cookies are not saving for some reason.

Comment: `Auth::user()` is a user object but `X-Forwarded-User` header is a string (or array of strings). The two will never match so `Auth::user() != $forwardedUser` is always true

Comment: Thanks apokryfos - I realsied that throughout my testing today. But the issue here is that Auth::login doesn't seem to persist. I've updated the code about with two comments to hopefully make that clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although login was working every time (but not persisting between page reloads), updating my User model path fixed my issue.

For some reason or another, I'd previously changed my User model to App\User.

Moving it back to App\Models\User (and updating all relevant references) made solved my issue.